# The pod `TensorFlow-experimental` is not found

Tags: tensorflow

I download the tensorflow from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/ios

And then install it step by step.

When I install pod, there is an ERROR:
[image]

Is the `TensorFlow-experimental` being renamed or Somethins wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. I ended up reinstalling and updating to the most current version of CocoaPods(1.2.1)

```
tensorflow/examples/ios/simple/ $ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `TensorFlow-experimental`

tensorflow/examples/ios/simple/ $ pod repo remove master

Removing spec repo `master`
tensorflow/examples/ios/simple/ $ pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
  $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --progress
  Cloning into 'master'...
  remote: Counting objects: 1342352, done.
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2372/2372), done.
  remote: Total 1342352 (delta 1560), reused 2050 (delta 796), pack-reused 1339018
  Receiving objects: 100% (1342352/1342352), 405.31 MiB | 370.00 KiB/s, done.
  Resolving deltas: 100% (673537/673537), done.
  Checking out files: 100% (162776/162776), done.

CocoaPods 1.3.0.beta.1 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.3.0.beta.1

Setup completed
tensorflow/examples/ios/simple/ $ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing TensorFlow-experimental (1.1.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `tf_simple_example.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
tensorflow/examples/ios/simple/ $ pod --version
1.2.1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! @Jonathon

Answer (score 0):

You can add the repo search path to the head of your Podfile.

```
source 'git@git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

And `pod install` again.

Answer (score 0):

Close Xcode.
In terminal at root of project, where the pod file lives, 
issue command "pod update"
first time, and after any update.

```
MacBook-Pro-2:camera $ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `TensorFlow-experimental`
MacBook-Pro-2:camera $ pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/XXXXXX/.cocoapods/repos/master fetch origin
  --progress
  remote: Counting objects: 2006922, done.        
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (403/403), done.        
  remote: Total 2006922 (delta 3740), reused 3789 (delta 3625), pack-reused 2002871        
  Receiving objects: 100% (2006922/2006922), 511.53 MiB | 665.00 KiB/s, done.
  Resolving deltas: 100% (1146145/1146145), completed with 960 local objects.
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
     58e4aaa8dab..224ab2278f7  master                -> origin/master
   * [new branch]              backz                 -> origin/backz
   * [new branch]              predates_sharding_branch -> origin/predates_sharding_branch
   * [new branch]              swift_version_support -> origin/swift_version_support
   * [new tag]                 v0.32.1               -> v0.32.1
   * [new tag]                 20161019              -> 20161019
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/XXXXXXX/.cocoapods/repos/master rev-parse
  --abbrev-ref HEAD
  master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/XXXXXXX/.cocoapods/repos/master reset --hard
  origin/master
  HEAD is now at 224ab2278f7 [Add] Taplytics_tvOS 2.25.2
warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing TensorFlow-experimental (1.1.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `tf_camera_example.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
```